# How to combine my array and json result in one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to combine two json results, but im struggling getting it done..

first one (`galleryData`):

```
[
      { "userId": 2, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
      { "userId": 4, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
]
```

second one (`combinations`):

```
{
  data: [
    { round: 1, partner: 2 },
    { round: 2, partner: 4 }
  ]
}
```

the output im expecting:

```
{
  data: [
    { round: 1, userId: 2, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
    { round: 2, userId: 4, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } }
  ]
}
```

Basically I need the `profileImage` from one of my result and map it to the correct user id

What I tried so far with no success:

```
let combinedResult = galleryData["userId"].map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, combinations[i]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and on each callback use `find` to find the corresponding `userId === partner`

```js
const galleryData = [
      { "userId": 2, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
      { "userId": 4, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
]

const combinations = {
  data: [
    { round: 1, partner: 2 },
    { round: 2, partner: 4 }
  ]
}

let combinedResult = { 
  data: galleryData.map((item, i) => {
    let combination = combinations.data.find(c => c.partner === item.userId);
    return { ...item, round: combination.round } 
  })
};

console.log(combinedResult)
```

Comment: thank you very much for providing your solution, appreciate it! Could you give me some usefull ressources getting better with arrays,maps doing operations like this? I really need to learn more about it

Comment: Sure, you should have a good knowledge with these array methods [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: And [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 1):

I think a little try using `Array.forEach` and then merge the Objects

```js
a = [
          { "userId": 2, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
          { "userId": 4, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
    ]
    
        b = {
          data: [
            { round: 1, partner: 2 },
            { round: 2, partner: 4 }
          ]
        }
// inside forEach you can write the logic to get elements from array 'a' as you can use `find` to check which user is needed 
    
        b.data.forEach((i,e) => { b.data[e] = {...i, ...a[e]} })

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be helpful.

```js
let galleryData = [
      { "userId": 2, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
      { "userId": 4, "profile": { "profileImage": "image" } },
];
let galleryDataAsUserId = {};
galleryData.forEach(elem=>{
    galleryDataAsUserId[elem.userId] = elem;
})
let combinations = {
  data: [
    { round: 1, partner: 2 },
    { round: 2, partner: 4 }
  ]
};
let data = combinations.data;
data.map(elem=>{
    let newElem = elem;
    newElem.profile = galleryDataAsUserId[elem.partner].profile;
});
console.log(data)
```